# Angularjs - asynchronous load of the element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say I have a angular view which gets populated from the service:

```
$http.get("" + window.ENDPOINT + "/main_things/" + $scope.mainThingId + ".json").success(function(data) {
  return $scope.main_thing = data;
});
```

Let's say I want to load another bit of information to my page, but the other bit is utilizing some slow external services, so I want to load it asynchronously:

```
$http.get("" + window.ENDPOINT + "/secondary_things/" + $scope.parentMainThingId + ".json").success(function(data) {
  return $scope.secondary_thing = data;
});
```

How can I structure my code in the angular controller so I can load the main_thing first and then load the secondary thing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By running second request in first request's success callback:

```
$http.get("" + window.ENDPOINT + "/main_things/" + $scope.mainThingId + ".json")
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.main_thing = data;
    $http.get("" + window.ENDPOINT + "/secondary_things/" + $scope.parentMainThingId + ".json")
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.secondary_thing = data;
    });
  });
```